# How to Change (image and fuction ) Button with another

Tags: java, android, xml, button

how to change image button with another image button for example : 
Play and Pause

Answer (score 1):

You can just change the icon on the button, instead of changing the entire button.
To change the icon programmatically you can just do this:

```
ImageButton btn = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.button);
btn.setImageResource(R.drawable.your_image);
```

If however, you wish to replace the button with a different button, you can create two buttons in the same location using a RelativeLayout, and then hide or show the buttons, based on what you want.
To do this:

```
ImageButton playBtn = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.play);
ImageButton pauseBtn = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.pause);
playBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
pauseBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to change the button, just the text / icon on the button.

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_play_pause);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (playing) {
            playing = false;
            button.setText("PLAY");
        } else {
            playing = true;
            button.setText("PAUSE");
        }
    }
});
```

Further reading: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html

Comment: i want to change the fuction of button also

Comment: You don't need to change the function! Just use an  if  statement to see in which state the button is and react accordingly.